# Windows: is it possible access window 'git bash' or 'ConEmu' via ssh?

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd, git-bash, conemu

I'm using `Windows7` desktop and installed ssh to access this `Windows7` desktop remotely.

In `Windows7` environment, I use `ConEmu` or `git bash`, which makes `Window7`env similar with `Linux`.

The Problem is that when I access this `Windows 7` via ssh, it shows `cmd` pane.

Is there any way to show `git bash` or `ConEmu` interface instead of `cmd` when accessing via ssh?

Answer (score 0):

You should at least be able to call a bash (simply by typing `bash`) from the CMD you see through your ssh session.
If you cannot, it means the `PATH` given you by your remote ssh session does not include `C:\path\to\Git\bin`.
In that case, <del>copy `C:\path\to\Git\bin\bash.exe` to `C:\Windows\System32`</del> that won't work, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219526/windows-is-it-possible-access-window-git-bash-or-conemu-via-ssh/48220166?noredirect=1#comment83453110_48220166) by [Maximus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405560/maximus)).

As I mention, look for an `sshd_config` file on your server, and add the right path as [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332534/7490).

Comment: I follow your instruction and `bash` command works in my remote shell, but the interface doesn't change. In short, when I access via `ssh` and type `bash`, nothing has happend... `ls` doesn't work..

Comment: @user3595632 can you, in your ssh session, type `where bash` to confirm it at least find `bash.exe`? Also what `set PATH` return (when typed in your ssh session).

Comment: `where bash` -> `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`. And  `set PATH` -> Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsP
owerShell\v1.0\;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Comment: @user3595632 Any chance you can modify your ssh daemon in order to include C:\path\to\git\usr\bin in your PATH as offered by ssh?

Comment: Sorry but cannot understand what u said. What is the meaning of "modify your ssh daemon"? and what is `C:\path\to\git\usr\bin`? Does git has bin folder?

Comment: @user3595632 When you access Windows7 through ssh, that means you have an ssh daemon, a listener, on said Windows 7: which SSH program are you using on that server to listen to ssh queries?

Comment: @user3595632 And yes, git has a bin folder: on your Windows 7 (not through ssh but directly no it), type `where git`

Comment: I followed this instruction : https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server. Please tell me if this one is not good ssh daemon :) and really appreciate your all comments !!

Comment: @user3595632 look for an sshd_config file on your server, for you to add the right path: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332534/7490

Comment: @user3595632 Windows 7 installation can't have `bash.exe` in the `system32` folder. That is some third-party application which may even harm your system.

Comment: @Maximus Good point. I have edited the answer to make it clearer this is not a good option.

Comment: @Maximus: is there something special about `bash.exe` that makes it not work in `\windows\system32`?  I can put 3rd party programs in there and have them work

Comment: @MichaelBurr You can put 64-bits third-party in there, not 32 (https://superuser.com/a/933335/141). And if the OP has installed a 32-bits Git for Windows... that wouldn't work.

Comment: So what is the conclusion? I have added git's `bin` path to system `PATH` and I also found out `sshd-config` but it is empty. There is no directory path, called `~/.ssh`. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3595632 That is expected (unless you have the very latest Windows 10 Creator 1709, in which case openssh is already installed: https://poweruser.blog/enabling-the-hidden-openssh-server-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-1709-and-why-its-great-51c9d06db8df). But if not, check http://diddy.boot-land.net/ssh/files/ssh_openssh.htm: Did you found sshd_config in `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\etc\sshd_config`? That is where you must put the line `PermitUserEnvironment yes`. THen restart the ssh daemon, and try for testing: ssh yourServer "export PATH=$PATH:/c/path/to/git/bin; echo $PATH; which bash"

Comment: @VonC I opened `sshd_config` in and there are a lot of contents inside. changed `PermitUserEnvironment` from `no` to `yes` and restart this window server. You said after I access my window server by ssh and type `export PATH=$PATH:/c/path/to/git/bin; ` right? But when I accessed via `ssh`, its interface is `cmd` so I can not set  `PATH` variable since this is `cmd`...

Comment: @user3595632 if it is a CMD (and not a shell), then type: `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\git\bin&& echo %PATH%&& where bash`: note the lack of space between a command and `&&`. That is intentional.

Comment: @user3595632 Actually, the command to type should be: `cmd /v /c "set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\git\bin&& echo !PATH!&& where bash"` Note the `!PATH!` syntax.

Comment: Still doesn't work : `chois@CHOIS-PC C:\Users\Chois>cmd /v /c "set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin&& echo !PATH!&& where bash
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Sublime Tex
t 3;C:\Users\Chois\Miniconda3;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\;C:\Pr
ogram Files\Git\mingw64\bin`
정보: 제공된 패턴에 해당되는 파일을 찾지 못했습니다.

Comment: Error in English : can not find file for given pattern.

Comment: @user3595632 If my korean is not too rusty, that was "Info: The file corresponding to the provided pattern was not found." I wonder what part of the line trigger this? Can you try: `echo %PATH%` just to see if this command works, and what your default PATH looks like?

Comment: `chois@CHOIS-PC C:\Users\Chois>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Sublime Tex
t 3;C:\Users\Chois\Miniconda3;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;`

Comment: @user3595632 So... `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` is already part of your PATH. Can you try, in your ssh session, `where bash`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163093/discussion-between-vonc-and-user3595632).